# How to build uboot for device using old include-style config files?

Tags: arm, bootloader, boot, porting, u-boot

I am trying to port some custom board-support patches from old (2012-ish) Uboot to something slightly more recent (around 2018). Of course a lot has changed in meantime. However, I managed to sort out most of stuff, but got stuck on building it. Uboot now uses Kconfig, but the patches I have only have a config file in form of *.h include file. Probably the best way would be to just convert it to Kconfig, which I intend to do eventually, but right now I need to get it up and running quick. I just need to verify whether it works first, and then if so, do the polishing. Question is : is it possible to build Uboot using the old config files and how to do it ? boards.cfg does not seem to exist anymore, so how do I let Uboot "know" about my board ?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I tried playing with Kconfig to no avail (I need to study it more, but as I mentioned, I'm on tight schedule right now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  As you noted, the old "boards.cfg" file doesn't exist.  You must move at least some of the symbols in to Kconfig in order to be able to build anything.  At a very bare minimum, TARGET_WHATEVER, and then in the board directory Kconfig file, SYS_BOARD/SYS_VENDOR/SYS_CONFIG_NAME need to be set.  But it will be a lot more painful overall if you don't also move everything that was migrated to Kconfig in that newer-but-not-latest version over to the defconfig as well.  You'll have a near-unreadable level of redefined warnings otherwise.

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for your answer. Could you please give me some pointers on where to start then ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: We don't currently have a basic guide to adding a new board.  You're likely best off looking at how a similar platform was added (use git log on some of the files in the board directory) and doing similar.